# Target @import in jQuery with no ID and no other attributes

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function adjustStyle(width) {
        width = parseInt(width);
        if (width < 701) {
            $(('style[type="text/css"]).attr([href=*400*]')).text('@import url("css/styles_400.css");');
        } else if ((width >= 701) && (width < 900)) {
            $(('style[type="text/css"].attr([href=*400*]')).text('@import url("css/styles_800.css");');
        } else {
           $(('style[type="text/css"].attr([href=*400*]')).text('@import url("css/styles_normal.css");');
        }
    }

    $(function() {
        adjustStyle($(this).width());
        $(window).resize(function() {
            adjustStyle($(this).width());
        });
    });
});
```

It's a styleswitcher. [I get this code from here](http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/), but I have modificated a little because the webportal I'm making will merge all css in the server, so, I must @import the stylesheet to target only one css and change it properly.

I can't give a title or an ID to the imported css (it's dynamic), and I tried the above code because the only code I have is:

```
  <style type="text/css">@import url('css/styles_400.css');</style>
```

As you see, the only clue I have is the URL.

**How can I target this css?** I have very little skills in jQuery, and I'm pretty sure that I'm doing something wrong with my code... but can't find the appropiate method to target it.

**Why I'm using this old styleswitcher instead of mediaqueries?** Because I need it for IE7 *(client requirements - I'm sure they hunting mammoths on saturdays)*, and they don't like both respond.js and css3-mediaqueries because are causing weird errors in Plone.

Comment: If the aim is to change the styles based on the browser width a pure CSS solution using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) would be a better option.

Comment: Oh, yes, I forget... I can't use mediaqueries... I will update the question ;)

Comment: "client requirements - I'm sure they hunting mammoths on saturdays" I actually laughed loudly at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, and after some hours playing around, I find a solution:

$(document).ready(function() {

```
function adjustStyle(width) {
    width = parseInt(width);
    if (width < 701) {
        $('style:contains("styles")').text('@import url("css/styles_400.css");');
    } else if ((width >= 701) && (width < 900)) {
        $('style:contains("styles")').text('@import url("css/styles_800.css");');
    } else {
       $('style:contains("styles")').text('@import url("css/styles_normal.css");');
    }
}

$(function() {
    adjustStyle($(this).width());
    $(window).resize(function() {
        adjustStyle($(this).width());
    });
});
```

});

It's similar to *jk.* code, I deleted `.html` method because with that, I can't target properly the CSS, but all @import CSS's.

Also, I have changed the keyword, because when the page loads "styles_800" there's no "400'" string elsewhere....

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

**UPDATED:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function adjustStyle(width) {
        width = parseInt(width, 10);
        if (width < 701) {
            $('style:contains("400")').empty().html('@import url("/css/style_400.css");');
        } else if ((width >= 701) && (width < 900)) {
            $('style:contains("400")').empty().html('@import url("css/styles_800.css");');
        } else {
           $('style:contains("400")').empty().html('@import url("css/styles_normal.css");');
        }
    }

    $(function() {
        adjustStyle($(window).width());
        $(window).resize(function() {
            adjustStyle($(this).width());
        });
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XLkRN/3/

Resize might be a little wonky in the fiddle. If resize fires multiple times on your page, you can put it in a timeout. Lots of advice on that on the web.

Comment: Thanks, but actually the Plone limitations don't allow me to use even the "title" attr :( What I need, I think, it's to target the css by the URL, with a wildcard or something, as I tried in my code... I have removed the title in the question because it hasn't sense.

Comment: I tested this code. The problem is that we have two or three CSS with the @import method. When I apply your code, the new styles override all these CSS's, not only the "styles_400" one...