# jQuery doesn't work in IE7, IE8 and IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have this code, is a styleswitcher that changes an `@import` CSS depending on the resolution. It works great in Firefox and Chrome, but not in IE (IE7, IE8 and IE9).

I have cleared chaché, validate successfully my html. I don't know why it isn't working :(

**Relevant HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<!--Typical stuff, (<head>, <meta>, etc) here -->
<style type="text/css">@import url('css/MQ.css');</style>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function adjustStyle(width) {
        width = parseInt(width);
        if (width < 701) {
            $('style:contains("MQ")').text(function () {
            return $(this).text().replace(/\d*MQ\.css/, "400MQ.css");
            });
        } else if ((width >= 701) && (width < 900)) {
            $('style:contains("MQ")').text(function () {
            return $(this).text().replace(/\d*MQ\.css/, "800MQ.css");
            });         
        } else {
           $('style:contains("MQ")').text(function () {
            return $(this).text().replace(/\d*MQ\.css/, "MQ.css");
            });         
        }
    }

    $(function() {
        adjustStyle($(this).width());
        $(window).resize(function() {
            adjustStyle($(this).width());
        });
    });
});
```

(I can't use mediaqueries to accomplish the work, because my client don't want pollyfills.)

Comment: So it's not jQuery that's not working, it's that IE's not reloading a stylesheet when you dynamically change the `@import` URL?

Comment: Why are you using a .ready() handlers inside another?

Comment: @Starx I don't know jQuery... I have edited a styleswitcher I've found to make it works for my requiremnts. You can see the evolution of the code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17069626/target-import-in-jquery-with-no-id-and-no-other-attributes/17104016#17104016) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104416/replacing-dynamic-content-jquery-javascript). To be honest, I am making changes blindly :/ I'm trying to learn! :D

Comment: @Rup I'm not sure... using firebug I can see in the `<head>`tag the replacement in the output code, but didn't see anything in IE developing tool. I don't know if it's the code, the IE's developer tool or the switch proccess what is failing.

Comment: Is a similar problem to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491882/css-styles-not-being-loaded-in-ie8

Comment: @Edorka No it isn't, the problem is the jQuery code, I think. If I import only the stylesheets, they are working properly.